# How do I center a div using javascript and not jQuery? (fixed div, gradient border, dynamic size, autocenter)

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, centering, css-position

I'm currently working on writing code for a MediaWiki website. I don't have permission to access and modify the LocalSettings.php (a hard-to-contact engineer does) where I'd normally type in a couple of lines to enable the MediaWiki-friendly version of Javascript.

I've already written the code in jQuery to work the way I want it to, but I need it rewritten in Javascript.

Getting the inner div to respect the boundaries of the dynamically sized outer div was a bit of a nightmare because of the way percentages *aren't* calculated with margins and padding, but I figured it out.

In any case, please check this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSGCy/2/) and help me understand how the code could be written for javascript.

For those not interested in looking at the jfiddle, I've provided the jQuery code here:

```
// This centers the div when the page first loads
$('.popup-border').css('margin-left', '-' + ($('.popup-border').outerWidth() / 2) + 'px');
$('.popup-border').css('margin-top', '-' + ($('.popup-border').outerHeight() / 2) + 'px');

// This centers the div each time the page is resized
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.popup-border').css('margin-left', '-' + ($('.popup-border').outerWidth() / 2) + 'px');
    $('.popup-border').css('margin-top', '-' + ($('.popup-border').outerHeight() / 2) + 'px');
});
```

**How can I rewrite this in javascript, and not jQuery?**

Comment: FYI, MediaWiki ships and uses jQuery by default since maaany releases ago.